# Anti-Tumbleweed-Badge

Tags: feature-request, badge-request, tumbleweed-badge

Not quite like necromancer I think there should be silver and gold badges for answering *a number of questions* (5/50) that previously have been *"awarded"* the tumbleweed status.

This might require that questions get automagically tagged with a system tag called tumbleweed <strike>so that people can find these kind of questions.</strike>

Just because I didn't get an answer doesn't mean I'd wouldn't appreciate one even 1 year later. I know one might say that "why should I answer a question so late if there's no guarantee for an acceptance?" etc, but I guess you can choose to do so based on the "askers" profile.

Thanks for your time

**Edit** I guess you can find these questions by clicking on the [tumbleweed badge](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/63/tumbleweed) as Borror0 pointed out, but might not be as obvious as searching for a tumbleweed tag. Still my badge request/suggestion remains

Comment: "This might require that questions get automagically tagged with a system tag called tumbleweed so that people can find these kind of questions." You mean like [this one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/38/tumbleweed)?

Comment: @Borror0 Tumbleweed is one-time only, so it could only ever mark one question per user. As well, that's stored with the author, not the question itself.

Comment: And also how could I search for questions that are both tumbleweed and Java or whatever the "Hunters" specialties are

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The revival badge already covers this ground. I don't think there is a need for an other badge.

> Answered more than 30 days later **as first answer** scoring 2 or more